# "Easter Egg" in link - activated by CTRL + click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project for a client, and we want to make a easter egg, when you click some of the letters in the logo.

There are three letters, and you have to click in the right order, before it activates the easter egg. However, because it's in a link, I wondered if I could use CTRL+Click...? I've searched the web, but couldn't get any answers...

Comment: Ctrl+clicking on a link opens the link in a new tab in most browsers.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do this if the letters are currently a link elsewhere.

Comment: You could make the combination Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Click to avoid having a user accidentally trigger your easter egg.  All of those keys are detectable from Javascript as the `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, and `altKey` member of the event object passed to the `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can do that

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    $('#link').click( function( event )
    {
      if ( event.ctrlKey )
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">Google</a>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll need to add your own logic to track the sequence of clicks on the three letters.

Answer (score 0):

The link could work, just have it execute a JavaScript method on the click rather than navigate to a page. Since you mentioned that there needs to be an order to the clicks, just have some variable's state transition based on the click sent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var track = 0;

function click_this(val) 
{
  // Manage your state here
}

</script>

T<a href="javascript:click_this(1);">e</a><a href="javascript:click_this(2);">s</a><a href="javascript:click_this(3);">t</a>
```